# Spark Converting JavaDStream<String> method to JavaPairDStream<String, String> method

Tags: java, scala, twitter, spark-streaming

I have this function in Spark Streaming code which splits the tweets into individual words

```
JavaDStream<String> words = statuses
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                    public Iterable<String> call(String in) {
                        return Arrays.asList(in.split(" "));
                    }
                });
```

I need to modify it so that it returns the words and the original tweet against each word. I have tried the below, But I am getting the `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable` error during run time.

```
    JavaPairDStream<String, String> wordTweets = statuses.flatMapToPair(
            new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, String>() {
                public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(String in){
                    Tuple2<String, String> tuple2 = new Tuple2(Arrays.asList(in.split(" ")), in);
                    return (Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>>) tuple2;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to get the functionality

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> locationspairRdd=OutStreamRDD.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, String>() {
    public Tuple2<String, String> call(String arg0) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
});
```